# Remove numbers from a string coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, trim

I need to remove the numbers which are at the end of a string and return the string which contains only characters. Is there any way? (for example if my string is abcd123456, then I want to remove 123456 and return abcd only)

Comment: Have you tried the regex.

Comment: Please see [Ask] and [MCVE].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With regex:

```
<cfset str = "abcd123456">
<cfset reg = ".+\D+(?=\d+)">
<cfset res = REMatchNoCase(reg, str)> <!--- array --->
<cfdump var="#res#">
```

Comment: It may not matter in the OP's case, but to match only values starting with non-digit's and ending with digits, shouldn't it just be `^\D+(?=\d+)`?

Answer (score 3):

**Use a Regex expression, like:**

```
foo = REReplaceNoCase('abcd123456','([^0-9]+).*','\1','ALL');
WriteOutput(foo);

//abcd
```

**The part of the Regex:**

```
[^0-9]+
```

Matches any character except a number

Comment: No need to capture. Just go: `reReplace("abcd123456", "[0-9]+$", "")`